# Adding JWT to Spring Boot Microservices

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, api, jwt

I currently have an app on aws that uses spring boot microservices for back-end and ReactJS for front-end.

The way it currently works is that a user logs in using username and password and a fetch call is made to an account microservice. There I do a basic username and pw check with db and send back a True or False response.

If True, the user gets logged in and redirected to products page where a fetch call is made to product service to get list of all products.

I now want to introduce JWT authorisation, so that calls to product service can only be made by logged in users.

My question is - can I introduce it in my current account service or do I have to put something in front of both services (currently they share a load balancer). Or maybe I need to direct product service traffic through account service?

Also, if I can introduce it in my current account service, how do I share the required key to product service so it can validate the request when it comes in?

Cheers, Kris

Comment: what  type of encryption algo are you planning to use in jwt

Comment: @satyesht Haven't gone that far into planning to be honest. Open to any solutions and good practices. What would you suggest?

Comment: This is a broad question.  Who will be your Oauth provider (i.e. AWS Cognito, Auth0, Okta, your own Keycloak, etc)?  Spring has [some articles](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) on implementing this but I don't think you'll get a simple answer here.  And encrypting JWT's is not needed over an HTTPS link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose the generic approach is to have an API Gateway layer i.e. a Microservice only which has to take care of following things -

1. Do the task of authentication and generate a JWT token for the user
2. Read the roles and responsibilities after decoding the token, every time a call is made by a user for authorization purpose
3. Once you get the role of user from here, you can create routes in API Gateway for each service to check like whether he can access that functionality or not, in your case let's say user's role is "warehouse Admin" and he is eligible to take care of product and related info, then he can access product service, for this you can do a role check at API Gateway layer only, when the request comes to access from routes related to product service (let's say its  "/products" ). Hence you are maintaining the authenticity checks at API Gateway layer only.
4. Or in the otherwise case if you want to maintain an account service as well to take care of doing the authentication and authorization, then you have to direct the calls from API Gateway to account service and route the request to related backend services, once the response arrives from account service carrying the roles and permissions for the user.

Comment: so would you say I should create a 3rd microservice and put it in front of the two and use it for auth. Then reuse Account Service for something else such as bringing full account details, pw changes etc. ?

Comment: Would Auth service be then connected to AccountDB or would it call account service for username, pw information?

Comment: likely any of the two you can opt for, I guess and keeping a different service will be cool idea

Comment: hmm I am thinking for now I will change my account service to be that auth service since right now it only has one functionality to authorise the user anyway. Would it work if I then send the JWT token to front end and then attach it on fetch calls made to the product service or do I need a gateway?

Comment: actually can I configure my Application Load balancer to do what API Gateway would do when it comes to checking incoming requests for Auth?